# Create a global filter in Vue 3 using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm following this [course on Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-full-stack-vue-net-core-postgres/) but its content is outdated so I can't follow the same steps that the author has followed to create a global filter.

Also it looks like from Vue 3 documentation, [filters are no longer supported](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/filters.html#_3-x-update).

What I'm trying to do here is fairly simple, it just needs to take a price as a number and return it as string dollar price, for eg: take `100` and return `$100`.

This doesn't work for me.
My `main.ts` looks like this:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { Vue } from 'vue-class-component';
import { viewDepthKey } from "vue-router";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

Vue.filter('price', function(input: number){
  if(isNaN(input)){
    return "-";
  }
  return '$' + input.toFixed(2);
})

createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .mount("#app1");
```

This is the error:

```
src/main.ts:8:5
TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<Vue<unknown, {}, {}>>'.
     6 | import store from "./store";
     7 |
  >  8 | Vue.filter('price', function(input: number){
       |     ^^^^^^
     9 |   if(isNaN(input)){
    10 |     return "-";
    11 |   }
```

This is how I'm trying to use it in the template:

```
{{ item.product.price | price }}
```

Is there a way to make it work or should I be using some `computed property`?

**EDIT for a follow up question:**

My class looks like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import { IProductInventory } from "@/types/Product";
import format from "@/helpers/format";

@Options({
    name: "Inventory",
    components: {}
})
export default class Inventory extends Vue{
    inventory:IProductInventory[] = //Coming from an api call
}
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: you can make a library of format functions  and just use```{{ format.price(item.product.price) }}```

Answer (score 11):

in `./helpers/filters.ts`

```
const filters = {
  price(input: number) {
    if (isNaN(input)) {
      return "-";
    }
    return '$' + input.toFixed(2);
  }
}
export default filters;
```

install it globally where you create your app...

```
import filters from './helpers/filters'

const app = createApp(App);
app.config.globalProperties.$filters = filters
app.mount('#app')
```

then just do

```
{{ $filters.price( price ) }}
```

Comment: I'm coming from a language like C# where everything is so intuitive and works so beautifully, I'm amazed to see how rough this JS/ TS world is! :) I'm getting this warning now: `[Vue warn]: Property "format" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance`. Intellisense also shows this: `'format' is declared but its value is never read.Vetur(6133)` on this line `import format from "@/helpers/format";`. Just edited my question to show how my class looks like.

Comment: Can you please help me with this? I'm still unable to make it work.

Comment: updated, also should be extensible to more filters if you want them

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it still doesn't work. My current setup came with this line `createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount("#app1");` but I edited to make it look like yours but it still didn't work. If you can help me with a quick glance at my code, please do so and I'd appreciate it so much. It's here: https://github.com/affableashish/solar-coffee/tree/master/solarcoffee.frontend

Answer (score 2):

filter option is removed in Vue 3, so you could use a computed property that returns a function with parameter :

```
    get formatPrice(): string{
        return (price)=>{
             if(isNaN(input)){
               return "-"
             }else{
              //return other value
              }
      }
   }
```

instead of `{{ item.product.price | price }}` you'll have :

```
{{ formatPrice(item.product.price) }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. If I wanted to access it from other components as well, how can I make it available globally?

Comment: Also I'm getting 2 errors on line `return (price) => {` which are: 1.`Type '(price: any) => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.Vetur(2322)` and 2.`Parameter 'price' implicitly has an 'any' type.Vetur(7006)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a computed property or methods are ideal solution only if your filters are local. However, if your filters are global and you would like to use in multiple components/pages, it's easy to register a globalProperties instead.

[Vue3 migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/filters.html) has mentioned this in details.

An example of registering global properties are:

```
// main.js
const app = createApp(App)

app.config.globalProperties.$filters = {
  currencyUSD(value) {
    return '$' + value
  }
}
```

Then apply the `currentyUSD` filters to your template as below:

```
<template>
  <h1>Bank Account Balance</h1>
  <p>{{ $filters.currencyUSD(accountBalance) }}</p>
</template>
```